# springbatch partition vs parallel

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I need your help.
Here's the story that I want to program.

1. **call rest api each 5 targets(stores)**
   to get the `total number of orderId and orderIds` and save them to the repository.
2. select `total number of orderId and orderIds` **dividely**
   and call another rest api each 5 targets(stores) to get **order list**
   using as parameter `total number of orderId and orderIds`and save to the repository.

I want to know how should I do in the spring batch like partitioning, parallel steps...
Can you help me to organize the process of how to make it?

I am learning about partitioning and parallel steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Define a Job with two main steps:
  **Step 1: Fetch order data from the REST APIs.**
  **Step 2: Call another REST API to get the order list and save it to the repository.**
- Implement partitioning for each step to process multiple stores in parallel.

**Define the Job:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class OrderProcessingJobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    // Define your reader, processor, and writer beans

    @Bean
    public Job orderProcessingJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("orderProcessingJob")
                .start(fetchOrderDataStep())
                .next(getOrderListStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step fetchOrderDataStep() {
        // Step 1 configuration goes here
    }

    @Bean
    public Step getOrderListStep() {
        // Step 2 configuration goes here
    }
}
```

**Implement partitioning for each step:**

```
@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("fetchOrderDataStep")
            .partitioner("fetchOrderDataStep", partitioner())
            .step(fetchOrderDataStepSlave())
            .gridSize(5) // Number of parallel threads
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Partitioner partitioner() {
    return new StorePartitioner(); // A custom partitioner implementation
}

@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStepSlave() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("fetchOrderDataStepSlave")
            .<InputType, OutputType>chunk(5)
            .reader(reader(null))
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<InputType> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['targetStore']}") String targetStore) {
    // Implement your REST API reader
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}
```

**Call another REST API to get the order list and save it to the repository.**

```
@Bean
public Step getOrderListStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("getOrderListStep")
            .partitioner("getOrderListStep", partitioner())
            .step(getOrderListStepSlave())
            .gridSize(5) // Number of parallel threads
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step getOrderListStepSlave() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("getOrderListStepSlave")
            .<InputType, OutputType>chunk(5)
            .reader(orderListReader(null))
            .processor(orderListProcessor())
            .writer(orderListWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<InputType> orderListReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['targetStore']}") String targetStore) {
    // Implement your REST API reader for the order list
}
```

*for the new requirement as per the comment*

**Define a Job with two main steps (as before):**
a. Step 1: Fetch order data from the REST APIs.
b. Step 2: Call another REST API to get the order list and save it to the repository.

Use a Flow to define parallel steps for each target store.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class OrderProcessingJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    // Define your reader, processor, and writer beans

    @Bean
    public Job orderProcessingJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("orderProcessingJob")
                .start(fetchOrderDataFlow())
                .split(taskExecutor()) // Add this line to split the flow
                .add(getOrderListFlow())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow fetchOrderDataFlow() {
        FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow> flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("fetchOrderDataFlow");
        // Add all target store steps in parallel
        flowBuilder.split(taskExecutor())
                .add(fetchOrderDataStep1(), fetchOrderDataStep2(), fetchOrderDataStep3(), fetchOrderDataStep4(), fetchOrderDataStep5());
        return flowBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow getOrderListFlow() {
        FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow> flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("getOrderListFlow");
        // Add all target store steps in parallel
        flowBuilder.split(taskExecutor())
                .add(getOrderListStep1(), getOrderListStep2(), getOrderListStep3(), getOrderListStep4(), getOrderListStep5());
        return flowBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```

2: Define separate step beans for each target store:

```
// Step 1: Fetch order data from the REST APIs

@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStep1() {
    return createFetchOrderDataStep("fetchOrderDataStep1", "store1");
}

@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStep2() {
    return createFetchOrderDataStep("fetchOrderDataStep2", "store2");
}

@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStep3() {
    return createFetchOrderDataStep("fetchOrderDataStep3", "store3");
}

@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStep4() {
    return createFetchOrderDataStep("fetchOrderDataStep4", "store4");
}

@Bean
public Step fetchOrderDataStep5() {
    return createFetchOrderDataStep("fetchOrderDataStep5", "store5");
}

private Step createFetchOrderDataStep(String stepName, String targetStore) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(stepName)
            .<InputType, OutputType>chunk(5)
            .reader(reader(targetStore))
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

// Step 2: Call another REST API to get the order list and save it to the repository

```
@Bean
public Step getOrderListStep1() {
    return createGetOrderListStep("getOrderListStep1", "store1");
}

@Bean
public Step getOrderListStep2() {
    return createGetOrderListStep("getOrderListStep2", "store2");
}

@Bean
public Step getOrderListStep3() {
    return createGetOrderListStep("getOrderListStep3", "store3");
}

@Bean
public Step getOrderListStep4() {
    return createGetOrderListStep("getOrderListStep4", "store4");
}

@Bean
public Step getOrderListStep5() {
    return createGetOrderListStep("getOrderListStep5", "store5");
}

private Step createGetOrderListStep(String stepName, String targetStore) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(stepName)
            .<InputType, OutputType>chunk(5)
            .reader(orderListReader(targetStore))
            .processor(orderListProcessor())
            .writer(orderListWriter())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for you help very much. I have another question. I really need your help.
The 5 targets(stores) rest apis have different url, different method(post,get), and different response. The main goal is to save the order information and payments information among startdate and enddate in 5 stores. But the table that write down is same. So I was trying to use 5 parallel steps and partitioning it. Is it possible to make it? And I really thankful for your explaination.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use parallel steps with different REST API configurations (URL, method, response) for each target store. To achieve this, you can create separate step beans for each target store and then use a Flow to execute them in parallel. Here's how you can modify the previous example to handle different configurations for each target store:
Define a Job with two main steps (as before):
a. Step 1: Fetch order data from the REST APIs.
b. Step 2: Call another REST API to get the order list and save it to the repository.
Use a Flow to define parallel steps for each target store.

Comment: if you want some example i can provide you a one, maybe I can edit my answer and add it

Comment: Oh really? Thanks.

Here's the error I met and example I am trying to program. I cannot explain with this comment so I uploaded a question.

If you look at it, I really appreciate it;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189171/springbatch-no-context-holder-available-for-job-scope-error

Comment: consider using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor or other more advanced TaskExecutor implementations, which allow you to manage a pool of threads and control the maximum number of concurrent threads since , SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor spawns a new thread for each tasks and can lead to performance issues and high resource consumption if you're processing a large number of records

Comment: You have given a lot of help but, still there's a few question.

1.    On the top of flow, the error about the job parameters happened. How can I solve this error? and why the error happened?
2.    How can I add partitioning with pararrel steps?
3.    How can I call rest api each 5 targets for getting order list partly using the parameter orderIds and the total number of orderId and saving to the repository?

Could you give me another example with more details? Thank you.